# How can i show the image in php?

Tags: php, sql

I need help in showing the image in php. I want to show an image and certain text of a database and this later creates a dynamic link and goes to the page through the ID. In the following code the image you are looking for does not appear in the broswer but the text that comes from the database shows without problems ... Can anyone help me? Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Muud.jpg

```
<?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class='container' id='fadein1'>sds";
                echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>";
                    echo "$row{'image'}";
                    echo "<img src='upload/destaques/<?php echo [$row{'image'}]; ?>' id='imagem'>";
                    echo "<a href='testee.php?noticia={$row['id']}'>{$row['titulo']}</a><br>\n";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } else{
        echo"<h2>Não existe</h2>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: your basic syntax is wrong `[$row{'image'}]` should be `$row['image']` you alos have `<?php` embedded inside already started php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a whole bunch of syntax errors, should work:

```
<?php
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class='container' id='fadein1'>sds";
                echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>";
                    echo $row['image'];
                    echo "<img src='upload/destaques/".$row['image']."' id='imagem'>";
                    echo "<a href='testee.php?noticia=".$row['id']."'>".$row['titulo']."</a><br>\n";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } else{
        echo"<h2>Não existe</h2>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @LucasSantos You should accept the answer in that case.